# Can I rest or speed up time?

Tags: stalker-shadow-of-chernobyl

Can I sleep, rest or somehow speed up the time?

After several fruitless attempts to get back to the trader during the night, I have decided to stay at the hangar and try my luck the next day...do I really have to wait?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using the [STALKER Complete 2009](http://artistpavel.blogspot.com/2009/04/stalker-complete-2009.html) mod? If you're not, you should be, it fixes a lot of problems with the game and greatly improves it overall. One of the enhancements in it is a sleeping bag that's always in your inventory and allows you to do exactly what you're looking for. The link above has a list of all the other changes, take a look through, it's an extremely nice mod.

I don't think the un-modified game has any way to sleep, but I found a reference on a forum to being able to press <kbd>*</kbd> on the numpad to speed up time, and <kbd>-</kbd> to slow it back down. I have no idea if that actually works though.

Comment: I wanted to play it Vanilla, but I think I'll try that mod. Thanks.

Comment: @Bobby I pondered as well whether to go vanilla first, but then decided to use the Complete 2009 mod right away and never regretted it.

Answer (score 3):

Once you get a suit with Nightvision device, it becomes easy to navigate through the night.
Also don't forget your trusty flashlight, it's often more than enough.

Also avoid visiting the Cordon's trader once you go far away. The trader at BAR (Duty Territory) is better option after the beginning.

Comment: True, the night vision turned me into a nightstalker which embraced the darkness.